# Given a bipartite graph with node weight get ordered list of one type of node based on certain heuristic

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-algorithm, social-networking

Given a bi-partite graph with node weights for both type A and type B nodes as shown below:

[image]

I want to output an ordered list of type B nodes as defined by the following heuristic:

1. For each node of type B we sum over node weights of type A that this node has an edge with and multiply the sum with its own node weight to get  the node value.
2. We then select the node from type B which has the highest value and append it to the output set S.
3. We delete the selected node from type B and all the nodes it had an edge to from type A.
4. Go back to step 1 until any node in type B is left with an edge to a node in type A.
5. Append any remaining node of type B to the output set in order of its node weight.

The figure below shows an example:

[image]

For this example, the output set will be: **(Y, Z, X)**

The naive process will be to simply walk through this algorithm but assuming the bi-partite graph is huge, I am looking for the most efficient way to find the output set. Note, I just need the ordered list of type B nodes as output *without* the intermediate calculated values (eg. 50, 15, 2)

Comment: Are the node degrees typically much smaller than the number of nodes? If so then you could run through step 1, placing the resulting B nodes in a max heap by val, then repeatedly take the top node, adjust its neighbors neighbors values, then remove them from and reinsert them into the heap.

Comment: @Dave  It is only necessary to recalculate the neighbors neighbors value if the neighbors neighbors value is the next highest in the heap, since the adjusted values always go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a further refinement of the algo suggested by Dave in a comment.  It minimizes the number of times a node value needs to be recalculated.

1. run through step 1, placing the resulting B nodes in a max heap by val
2. check the top node if any of its neighbors are deleted.  If yes, recalculate and reinsert into heap.  If no, add to output and delete neighbors.
3. repeat 2 until all B are output

I have implemented this algorithm in C++ based on my [PathFinder graph class](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2).  The code, running on a 1 million node graph with half a and half b nodes, each b node connected to two random a nodes, requires 1 second.

Here is the code

```
void cPathFinder::karup()
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("karup");
        std::cout << "karup on " << nodeCount() << " node graph\n";
        std::vector<int> output;

        // calculate initial values of B nodes
        std::multimap<int, int> mapValueNode;
        for (auto &b : nodes())
        {
            if (b.second.myName[0] != 'b')
                continue;
            int value = 0;
            for (auto a : b.second.myLink)
            {
                value += node(a.first).myCost;
            }
            value *= b.second.myCost;
            mapValueNode.insert(std::make_pair(value, b.first));
        }

        // while not all B nodes output
        while (mapValueNode.size())
        {
            raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("select");

            // select node with highest value
            auto remove_it = --mapValueNode.end();
            int remove = remove_it->second;

            if (!remove_it->first)
            {
                /** all remaining nodes have zero value
                 * all the links from B nodes to A nodes have been removed
                 * output remaining nodes in order of decreasing node weight
                 */
                raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("Bunlinked");
                std::multimap<int, int> mapNodeValueNode;
                for (auto &nv : mapValueNode)
                {
                   mapNodeValueNode.insert( 
                       std::make_pair( 
                           node(nv.second).myCost,
                           nv.second ));
                }
                for( auto& nv : mapNodeValueNode )
                {
                    myPath.push_back( nv.second );
                }
                break;
            }

            bool OK = true;
            int value = 0;
            {
                raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("check");

                // check that no nodes providing value have been removed

                // std::cout << "checking neighbors of " << name(remove) << "\n";

                auto &vl = node(remove).myLink;
                for (auto it = vl.begin(); it != vl.end();)
                {
                    if (!myG.count(it->first))
                    {
                        // A neighbour has been removed
                        OK = false;
                        it = vl.erase(it);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // A neighbour remains
                        value += node(it->first).myCost;
                        it++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (OK)
            {
                raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("store");
                // we have a node whose values is highest and valid

                // store result
                output.push_back(remove);

                // remove neighbour A nodes
                auto &ls = node(remove).myLink;
                for (auto &l : ls)
                {
                    myG.erase(l.first);
                }
                // remove the B node
                // std::cout << "remove " << name( remove ) << "\n";
                mapValueNode.erase(remove_it);
            }
            else
            {
                // replace old value with new
                raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("replace");
                value *= node(remove).myCost;
                mapValueNode.erase(remove_it);
                mapValueNode.insert(std::make_pair(value, remove));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the timing results

```
karup on 1000000 node graph
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        1.16767 1.16767 karup
  581457        1.37921e-06     0.801951        select
  581456        4.71585e-07     0.274206        check
  564546        3.04042e-07     0.171646        replace
       1        0.153269        0.153269        Bunlinked
   16910        8.10422e-06     0.137042        store
```

Comment: If you don't adjust neighbors neighbors at each step, the heap has nodes in the wrong position. When you eventually need to reheapify something, it may not rise to the position it should b/c it is 'blocked' by a node with an incorrect large value.

Comment: If the node at the top of the heap has an incorrect value that could only be because some of its neighbors have been deleted.  So then, in step 2 it will be recalculated before being added to the output and placed lower in the heap.  Step 2 will then repeat until it find the blocked node.

Answer (score 1):

I provided a solution in C++ that basically resembles @ravenspoint 's idea. It maintains a heap and take the B node with the highest value each time. Here I used `priority_queue` instead of `set` cause the first one the much faster than the second one.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int nA, nB;
std::vector<int> A, B, sum;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adjA, adjB;
inline std::vector<int> solve() {
    struct Node {
        // We store the value of the node `x` WHEN IT IS INSERTED
        // Modifying the value of the node `x` (sum) won't affect this Node basically
        int x, val;

        Node(int x): x(x), val(sum[x] * B[x]) {}

        bool operator<(const Node &t) const { return val == t.val? (B[x] < B[t.x]): (val < t.val); }
    };

    std::priority_queue<Node> q;
    std::vector<bool> delA(nA, false), delB(nB, false);
    std::vector<int> ret; ret.reserve(nB);

    for (int x = 0; x < nA; ++x)
        for (int y : adjA[x]) sum[y] += A[x];
    for (int y = 0; y < nB; ++y) q.emplace(y);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        const Node node = q.top(); q.pop();
        const int y = node.x;
        if (sum[y] * B[y] != node.val || delB[y]) // This means this Node is obsolete
            continue;
        delB[y] = true;
        ret.push_back(y);
        for (int x : adjB[y]) {
            if (delA[x]) continue;
            delA[x] = true;
            for (int ny : adjA[x]) {
                if (delB[ny]) continue;
                sum[ny] -= A[x];
                // This happens at most `m` time
                q.emplace(ny);
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "Number of nodes in type A: "; std::cin >> nA;
    A.resize(nA); adjA.resize(nA);
    std::cout << "Weights of nodes in type A: ";
    for (int &v : A) std::cin >> v;

    std::cout << "Number of nodes in type B: "; std::cin >> nB;
    B.resize(nB); adjB.resize(nB); sum.resize(nB, 0);
    std::cout << "Weights of nodes in type B: ";
    for (int &v : B) std::cin >> v;

    int m;
    std::cout << "Number of edges: "; std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << "Edges: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        int x, y; std::cin >> x >> y;
        --x; --y;
        adjA[x].push_back(y);
        adjB[y].push_back(x);
    }

    auto st_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto ret = solve();
    auto en_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Answer:";
    for (int v : ret) std::cout << ' ' << (v + 1);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Took "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(en_time - st_time).count()
        << "ms" << std::endl;
}
```

I randomly generated some batches of data where `nA = nB = 1e6, m = 2e6`, and the program can always produce the answer in less than 800ms on my computer (not considering IO time, O2 enabled). The time complexity of this solution is `O((m+n)log m)` since the `emplace` called at most `n+m` time.

Sorry for my poor English. Feel free to point out my typos and mistakes.

Comment: "I used priority_queue instead of set cause the first one the much faster than the second one." I am surprised by this claim.  Do you have a citation for it?  Have you run timing tests to confirm it?  In my implementation I use a multimap to keep the B nodes in value order.  I prefer this to using a queue because being able to iterate over the contents is very helpful during debugging.  Once debugged, I tried replacing the multimap with a queue ( branch queue in Pathfinder repo )  There was no change in the time taken to process a million node graph.

Comment: Oh well, that was just a consensus in my community. In cases where we only need to insert elements and query the maximum value, using priority_queue is better for saving time than using set: though they both take O(logn) time, priority_queue maintains a heap which, at most of the time, has a smaller time complexity constant than the RB-Tree(most implementations) which set uses. I have some experiences where replacing the set in my code with priority_queue makes it faster significantly.

Comment: For benchmark, I created a simple one but I'm not sure if it's convincing. You could check it out: https://gist.github.com/Mivik/7a607df5fe240ac516bdcad6d41182e5

Comment: BTW, I googled around but I didn't find a proper explanation for the "branch queue" mentioned by you (branch queue on Wikipedia refers to branch prediction related stuff, which I think is not your actual meaning). Could you give a brief introduction of it or a link explaining it? Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the development branch name 'queue' in the PathFinder repo.  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/tree/queue